# How to get gujarati or hindi data from php to javascript using ajax services

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatable, datatables

I want to show hindi or gujarati data to the table using DataTable.js API.
i have following javascript code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // On page load: datatable
  var url = "<?php echo base_url();?>list?job=get_companies";
  var table_companies = $('#table_companies').dataTable({
    "ajax": url,
    "lang": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Gujarati.json",
    "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Gujarati.json"
            },
    "columns": [
      { "data": "id" },
      { "data": "text",   "sClass": "Text" },
      { "data": "userid" }

    ],
    "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [-1] }
    ],
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
    "oLanguage": {
      "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst":       " ",
        "sPrevious":    " ",
        "sNext":        " ",
        "sLast":        " ",
      },
      "sLengthMenu":    "Records per page: _MENU_",
      "sInfo":          "Total of _TOTAL_ records (showing _START_ to _END_)",
      "sInfoFiltered":  "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
    }
  });
  });
```

and then i was give response from php file look like (there is to three parameter to the array and the data have string of hindi or Gujarati data format thne how to set data using dataTable.js):

```
$data = array(
              "result"  => $result,
              "message" => $message,
              "data"    => $mysql_data
            );

            // Convert PHP array to JSON array
            $json_data = json_encode($data);
            print $json_data;
```

Comment: Okay....what happens now?

Comment: when i getting data from php using json_encode functionality then there was show me in javascript look like "???? ?? ??? ?????? ?? ?????? ????? ???" data.

Comment: Are you using phpmyadmin

Comment: yes of course ....

Comment: Try changing your field collation to utf8_unicode_ci.

Comment: there is to no problem when i am encode data to json it;s okay then i was to decode again encoded data it's give me fine result in php file but when i want this data to the javascript file with ajax call it's give me "??????????????????" like data

Comment: Well if anyone is going to help you you need to provide some code examples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133167/discussion-between-ankur-and-jethro-hazelhurst).